# TinyOS event return type meaning

Tags: tinyos, nesc

So in TinyOS an interface is composed of *commands* and *events*. When a module uses an interface, it calls its commands and provides an implementation of its events (provides an event handler).

The sense of the return type of a command is clear, it is the same as that of any function/method in any programming language, but, the return type of an event results unclear to me.

**Let's take an example:**

```
interface Counter{
    command int64_t getCounter(int64_t destinationId);
    event int64_t counterSent(int64_t destinationId);
}
```

Let's define a module that *provides* the Counter interface.

```
module Provider{
    provides interface Counter;
}

implementation {
    int64_t counter;
    counter = 75; //Random number

    /** 
    Returns the value of the counter and signals an event that
    someone with id equal to destinationId asked for the counter. 
    **/

    command int64_t getCounter(int64_t destinationId){
        int64_t signalReturnedValue;
        signalReturnedValue = signal counterSent(destinationId);
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Now let's define two module which *use* this interface.

```
module EvenIDChecker{
    uses interface Counter;
}
implementation{
    /**
    Returns 1 if the destinationId is even, 0 otherwise
    **/

    event int64_t counterSent(int64_t destinationId){
        if(destinationId % 2 == 0){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's define another module which *uses* the same interface but does the inverse of the EvenIDChecker module.

```
module OddIDChecker{
    uses interface Counter;
}
implementation{
    /**
    Returns 1 if the destinationId is odd, 0 otherwise
    **/

    event int64_t counterSent(int64_t destinationId){
        if(destinationId % 2 == 1){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, what would be the final value of the var **signalReturnedValue**?

Comment: When you compile nesC code, do you get a warning along the lines of `calls to Counter.counterSent in ... are uncombined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is unspecified or this code may even not compile.

In TinyOS, there's a concept of *combine functions*, which are of signature `type f(type, type)` and their purpose is to reasonably combine two values of the same type. For `error_t` there's such a function defined:

```
error_t ecombine(error_t e1, error_t e2) {
  return (e1 == e2) ? e1 : FAIL;
}
```

Combine function is called automatically in a situation such as in your code snippet.

If you want to define a combine function in this example, you need to typedef the return type of the event. See [4.4.3 Combine Functions](http://csl.stanford.edu/~pal/pubs/tos-programming-web.pdf) for more information.

Note that the situation is symmetric for commands. You can wire two implementations of an interface to a single `uses` declaration like this:

```
configuration ExampleC {
  ExampleP.Counter -> Counter1;
  ExampleP.Counter -> Counter2;
}
```

Assuming that `Counter` has a command that returns something, whenever `ExampleP` calls that command, two implementations are executed and two return values are combined.